# Difference between |= and ^= css

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is the difference between: `|=` and `^=` in css?

Due to this link it isn't one, but why would they bother for two things to be duplicates.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

[attribute|=value] and [attribute^=value]

First has

> Selects every  element whose src attribute value begins with
>   "https"

second has

> Selects all elements with a lang attribute value starting with "en"

Comment: You shouldn't use w3schools as a source! Check out [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: Yeah, but due to SEO from google I keep getting to them from first page search.

Comment: I'm aware of that. However, next time you'll know you should skip those links in search results :)

Comment: By the way, i don't think any of our answers **really** answered your question :D

Comment: Since both `^=` and `|=` will match both `en` and `en-US`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the official description in the w3c document says it all:

`E[foo|="en"]` - an E element whose foo attribute value is a hyphen-separated list of values beginning with en

`E[foo^="bar"]` - an E element whose foo attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar"

W3Schools documentation is imprecise at times, so for good documentation either go to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), or [Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/) or use the official [W3C Document](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#overview).

Basically the `|=` selector matches words optionally immediately followed by a hyphen (`-` or U+002D respectively) and is useful with compound-classes and languages attributes.

```
<div class="wrapper-inner"><span lang="en-GB">...</span></div>

div[class|='wrapper']{/*...*/}
span[lang|='en']{/*...*/}
```

`^=` is a bit more general, basically a "substring match" and behaves exactly like `^` in a regex would.

You can see the difference of how the two selectors match in the following example:

```css
*{
color:red;
/* now, if |= or ^= selector fails, the color is red */
}

[class|=en],[class^=de]{
color:green;
}
div::after{content:"FAIL"}
[class|=en]::after,[class^=de]::after{content:"pass"}
```

```html
<div class="en-US">Case 1.1: |=en matching "en-US": </div>
<div class="en">Case 1.2: |=en matching "en": </div>
<div class="en-">Case 1.3: |=en matching "en-": </div>
<div class="en,">Case 1.4: |=en matching "en,": </div>
<div class="english">Case 1.5: |=en matching "english": </div>
<div class="en ">Case 1.6: |=en matching "en ": </div>
<div class="de-DE">Case 2.1: ^=de matching "de-DE": </div>
<div class="de">Case 2.2: ^=de matching "de": </div>
<div class="de ">Case 2.3: ^=de matching "de ": </div>
<div class="deutsch">Case 2.4: ^=de matching "deutsch": </div>
```

Comment: `|=` matches words, while `^=` not.

Comment: @highmaintenance Since I assume the downvote comes from you, can you please elaborate where my answer exactly is incorrect? If I understand your comment correctly (it's quite ambiguously worded), it is incorrect: `lang="en"` - here I would regard `en` as a word and it would be targeted by both selectors - as it's supposed to. Or do you mean something different by "word"? For something like `lang="en-US"` you could argue what "word" means, but again both selectors would target this element. The only difference is `|=` explicitly requiring the `|` (U+002D) character.

Answer (score 5):

Please check following example. You will get better understanding between both selectors.

```css
/* select all lang attribute starting with "en" */
[lang^=en] {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

/* select all hyphen-separated lang attribute starting with "en" */
[lang|=en] {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p lang="en">Hello!</p>
<p lang="en-us">Hi!</p>
<p lang="en_gb">Ello!</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why using w3schools when the Official Documentation by W3C is out there ?

[W3C CSS3 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

[W3C CSS2 Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching)

> `E[foo^="bar"]` an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar"   (Attribute selectors CSS3)
>
> `E[foo|="en"]` an E element whose "foo" attribute has a hyphen-separated list of values beginning (from the left) with "en"    (Attribute selectors CSS2 )

Answer (score 2):

w3schools is not a good source of knowledge ([check that site](http://w3fools.com/)). You should rely on official [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/):

`E[foo^="bar"]`  an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar"

`E[foo|="en"]`  an E element whose "foo" attribute has a hyphen-separated list of values beginning (from the left) with "en"

*Examples of usages:*

> The following selector represents an a element for which the value of
>   the hreflang attribute begins with "en", including "en", "en-US", and
>   "en-scouse":
>
> `a[hreflang|="en"]`

> The following selector represents an HTML object, referencing an
>   image:
>
> `object[type^="image/"]`